# Oracle SQL Developer equivalent of "SELECT TOP xxx ROWS" in SQL Server

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

In SQL Server, we have the functionality of "SELECT TOP xxx ROWS" when we right click a table:

[image]

This will generate a SELECT statement with all the columns in selected table written in the new SQL statement. Is there any similar functionality in Oracle SQL Developer?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this.

1. RDBMS side
2. Client side (SQL*Developer)

## Client Side

In SQL*Developer, you can drag+drop the table from the Connection to the worksheet in order to get a `SELECT` statement.  A blog on it is [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/sqldev-tip-and-trick-drag-and-drop-to-worksheet/).

If you use the Query Builder, you can drag+drop multiple tables and SQL*Developer will create the `JOIN` syntax based on defined `FK`.
ThatJeffSmith-Oracle goes over the speed improvements for 18.2 [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/07/more-on-18-2-faster/).

In both cases, the `Top n rows` clause is not part of the resulting SQL statement.

## RDBMS

Oracle database introduced a `TOP n ROW` clause in 12c.

Example:  https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1